# void function returns nothing - C

Tags: arrays, c, string, for-loop, pointers

I'm starting my studies in C and i came across this function return problem. I created a function that prints the name of numbers up to 9, from an input number. Entering, i have no return from the function. I can't see where the error is.

This is my code:

```
void for_loop(int n1, char array[]){
    for(int index = n1; index <= 9; index++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[index]);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int num1 = 2;

    char* numbers[10] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};

    for_loop(num1, *numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The issue is how you declare the parameter `array` in the function. It should be `char* array[]` and you should pass it as `for_loop(num1, numbers);`

Comment: Yes, that’s what `void` means. What return value are you *expecting*?

Comment: @KonradRudolph he probably means "my function __does__ nothing".

Comment: `void for_loop(int n1, char *array[])`. You are passing 2D array but your function declaration has 1D array.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Exactly, it was a typo. Thanks for clarifying, I hadn't noticed.

Comment: You should activate and read your warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong:

You want this:

```
void for_loop(int n1, char *array[]) {
  for (int index = n1; index <= 9; index++) {
    printf("%s\n", array[index]);
  }
}

int main()
{
  int num1 = 2;

  char* numbers[10] = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

  for_loop(num1, numbers);
  return 0;
}
```

`for_loop(num1, *numbers)` is equivalent to `for_loop(num1, numbers[0])` which is equivalent to `for_loop(num1, "zero")`.

Comment: Um... I see, it was a problem with the pointer. I'm still learning and i'm still confused by the concept of pointers. I was able to see where i went wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @zangstrell just to be a bit more clear, `*numbers` is equivalent to `*(numbers + 0)` which is equivalent to `numbers[0]`, `*(numbers + 1)` is equivalent to `numbers[1]`, etc.